# Selecting all the 'id' and 'app_img_path' from the mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on an app but i want to select all the id and the image path from the database with a limit from the result but all i get from the `mysql_fetch_assoc($running)` is `Array( [id] => 1 [app_img_path] => images/1_subway_surfers.jpg)` but all i want to do is to select all the id(1 - 10) and all the image path not just one please how do i do that. this is my code 
**HTML**

```
<div id="andriod_menu">
            <div id="categories">
                <ul id='cat_con'>
                    <li id="Arc" data-app="arc_app" data-db-table="arcade_apps_andriod"><div id="Arc_txt">Arcade
                    <img src="images/ajax-loader (5).gif" id="loader_ard" value="ard">
                    </div></li>
                    <li id="Spo" data-app="spo_app" data-db-table="sports_apps_andriod"><div id="Spo_txt">Sports
                    <img src="images/ajax-loader (5).gif" id="loader_ard" value="spo">
                    </div></li>
                    <li id="act" data-app="act_app" data-db-table="action_apps_andriod"><div id="act_txt">Action
                    <img src="images/ajax-loader (5).gif" id="loader_ard" value="act">
                    </div></li>
                    <li id="adv" data-app="adv_app" data-db-table="adventure_apps_andriod"><div id="adv_txt">Adventure
                    <img src="images/ajax-loader (5).gif" id="loader_ard" value="adv">
                    </div></li>
                    <li id="sim" data-app="sim_app" data-db-table="simulation_apps_andriod"><div id="sim_txt">Simulation
                    <img src="images/ajax-loader (5).gif" id="loader_ard" value="sim">
                    </div></li>
                    <!--<li id="spo"><div id="spo_txt">sports</div></li>-->
                    <li id="rac" data-app="rac_app" data-db-table="racing_apps_andriod"><div id="rac_txt">Racing
                    <img src="images/ajax-loader (5).gif" id="loader_ard" value="rac">
                    </div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function li_categories()
        {
            //list of the 
            $('div>#loader_ard').hide();
            var cat_arr=
            [
            'Arc',
            'Spo',
            'act',
            'adv',
            'sim',
            'rac'
            ];


            jQuery.each(cat_arr, function() {
                //$('button[value="' + this + "]')
              $('#' + this ).click(function()
                {
                    $(this).find('#loader_ard').show();
                    cat_clicked=$(this).data('app');// this returns the data object...
                    db_selected=$(this).data('db-table');


                    //if the cat_click data matches the data on the db get the list of data from
                    // the db..

                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        url:"pages/func.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        data: {clicked:cat_clicked,db_selected:db_selected}

                    });


                });
            });




        }

        li_categories();
```

**PHP**

```
function cat_clicked()
{

if (isset($_POST['clicked']) && isset($_POST['db_selected'])) {
    $clicked=$_POST['clicked'];
    $db_selected=$_POST['db_selected'];

    include('db_con.php');
    // go the data base based on the db categories and fecth all the app data..
    $sqlbaba="SELECT `id`,`app_img_path` FROM `$db_selected`"; 
    $run=mysql_query($sqlbaba) or die(mysql_error());

    if ($running=mysql_query($sqlbaba)) {

        $ss=mysql_fetch_assoc($running);
        print_r($ss);

    }



}  

}
cat_clicked();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your function `mysql_fetch_assoc` only fetches **one** row.

To iterate all rows use this:

```
while ($ss=mysql_fetch_assoc($running)) {
    print_r($ss);
}
```

**Attention:**
Your current php code has **serious security problems**. You should use the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli)-Interface or [PDO](http://www.pdp.net/pdo).

This is because of

```
$db_selected=$_POST['db_selected'];
$sqlbaba="SELECT `id`,`app_img_path` FROM `$db_selected`";
```

So if I modify your `$_POST['db_selected'];` to something evil like `mysql_information; drop table $db_selected` I can easily destroy your application.

Comment: @Tjati +1 for mentioning PDI/MySQLi AND answering the question. Too many folks lately haven't done both. I also highly recommend the user learn one of those and improve their code. It's worth the time now for saving the headache in a year.

Comment: please am not familiar with pdo it looks a bit confusing... what of if    i do mysql_real_escape_string() on all the post data...

Comment: @omeinusch after doing all the while ($ss=mysql_fetch_assoc($running)) {
    print_r($ss);
} how do i get all the data to a variable or maybe to json encode because i have several 'id' values but i do not know to extract them seperatly.

Comment: Easy! You see, that $ss is now an array. So just access your `id`-value as in any other array: `$ss['id']`.